# Desabilitar final de semana e habilitar dias com Fullcalendar plugin Jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

Estou usando o plugin **fullcalendar.js**

Como faria para deixar desabilitado os finais de semana e também deixar habilitado apenas 15 dias contando com a data de hoje?

Tenho esse código com o plugin **fullcalendar.js**

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        allDaySlot: false,
        weekends: false,
        validRange: {
            start: moment().day(), // data atual
            end: moment().add(15, 'days') // data atual + 14 (15 com a data atual)
        },
        viewRender: function(i) {
            var ini = moment();
            if (ini >= i.start && ini <= i.end) {
                $(".fc-prev-button")
                    .prop('disabled', true)
                    .addClass('fc-state-disabled');
            } else {
                $(".fc-prev-button")
                    .removeClass('fc-state-disabled')
                    .prop('disabled', false);
            }
        },

        events: "index.php?view=1",


        eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
            endtime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.end).format('h:mm');
            starttime = $.fullCalendar.moment(event.start).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
            var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
            $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
            $('#modalWhen').text(mywhen);
            $('#eventID').val(event.id);
            $('#calendarModal').modal();
        },

        //header and other values
        select: function(start, end, jsEvent) {
            endtime = $.fullCalendar.moment(end).format('h:mm');
            starttime = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm');
            var mywhen = starttime + ' - ' + endtime;
            start = moment(start).format();
            end = moment(end).format();
            $('#createEventModal #startTime').val(start);
            $('#createEventModal #endTime').val(end);
            $('#createEventModal #when').text(mywhen);
            $('#createEventModal').modal('toggle');
        },
        eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                data: 'action=update&title=' + event.title + '&start=' + moment(event.start).format() + '&end=' + moment(event.end).format() + '&id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    //alert(json);
                }
            });
        },
        eventResize: function(event) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'index.php',
                data: 'action=update&title=' + event.title + '&start=' + moment(event.start).format() + '&end=' + moment(event.end).format() + '&id=' + event.id,
                type: "POST",
                success: function(json) {
                    //alert(json);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    $('#submitButton').on('click', function(e) {
        // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
        e.preventDefault();
        doSubmit();
    });

    $('#deleteButton').on('click', function(e) {
        // We don't want this to act as a link so cancel the link action
        e.preventDefault();
        doDelete();
    });

    function doDelete() {
        $("#calendarModal").modal('hide');
        var eventID = $('#eventID').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data: 'action=delete&id=' + eventID,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                if (json == 1)
                    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventID);
                else
                    return false;


            }
        });
    }

    function doSubmit() {
        $("#createEventModal").modal('hide');
        var title = $('#title').val();
        var startTime = $('#startTime').val();
        var endTime = $('#endTime').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            data: 'action=add&title=' + title + '&start=' + startTime + '&end=' + endTime,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(json) {
                $("#calendar").fullCalendar('renderEvent', {
                        id: json.id,
                        title: title,
                        start: startTime,
                        end: endTime,
                    },
                    true);
            }
        });

    }
});
```

**Não está deixando habilitado os 15 dias contando com a data de hoje**

```
header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            editable: true,
            selectable: true,
            allDaySlot: false,
            weekends: false,
            validRange: {
   start: moment().day(),         // data atual
   end:  moment().add(15, 'days') // data atual + 14 (15 com a data atual)
},
viewRender: function(i){
   var ini = moment();
   if(ini >= i.start && ini <= i.end){
      $(".fc-prev-button")
      .prop('disabled', true) 
      .addClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
   }else{
      $(".fc-prev-button")
      .removeClass('fc-state-disabled')
      .prop('disabled', false); 
   }
},
```

Answer (score 3):

Para ocultar os fins de semana use a opção:

```
weekends: false,
```

Para começar da data atual use a opção:

```
firstDay: moment().day(),
```

Para definir o número de dias (no caso 15 dias pra frente contado com a data atual) use a opção:

```
validRange: {
   start: moment().day(),         // data atual
   end:  moment().add(15, 'days') // data atual + 14 (15 com a data atual)
},
```

Mas também é preciso desabilitar a seta que volta para dias anteriores à data atual. Para isso use a função da opção `viewRender`. Ela verifica se a *view* do calendário é maior que a semana da data atual e desabilita ou habilita a seta (mudando a classe) de visualizar datas anteriores à data atual:

```
viewRender: function(i){
   var ini = moment();
   if(ini >= i.start && ini <= i.end){
      $(".fc-prev-button")
      .prop('disabled', true) 
      .addClass('fc-state-disabled'); 
   }else{
      $(".fc-prev-button")
      .removeClass('fc-state-disabled')
      .prop('disabled', false); 
   }
},
```

Comment: Não está deixando habilitado os 15 dias contando com a data de hoje, fiz como você falou, editei minha pergunta, olha aí por favor, o restante funcionou!

Answer (score -2):

`selectConstraint: 
{
        start: $.fullCalendar.moment().subtract(1, 'hour'),
        end: $.fullCalendar.moment().startOf('now').add(15, 'day')
}`